# fullcalendar: get days of the week in clientevent

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

If I have an array of days:

```
var days=[2,5] (corresponds to Tuesday and Friday)
```

How can I find out how many days in the array fall in a clientevent such as the following one:

```
 var holiday= {title: holiday,
               start: 2015-10-20,
               end: 2015-10-30}
```

I don't need to know how many of each day falls in the event, but only the total. So in this case the script would return '4' (2 tuesdays and 2 fridays in the event).

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the dates and see if the `arr.indexOf` the current day of week is `>= 0`, look:

```js
var arr = [2, 5];

var holiday = {
  title: holiday,
  start: '2015-10-20',
  end: '2015-10-30'
}

var st = new Date(holiday.start),
    en = new Date(holiday.end);

var cont = 0;

while (st <= en) {
  if (arr.indexOf(st.getUTCDay()) >= 0) {
    cont++;
  }
  st.setDate(st.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(cont);
```

Note: you must use `getUTCDay()` instead of `getDay()` because of the Time Zone differences.